# SWFUPLOAD stuck on pending

Tags: javascript, swfupload

im trying to use swfupload on my website and have followed all the instructions to the bone. now, when i select a file, all i see is pending.. it never goes any further. here is my implementation

```
    var swfu = new SWFUpload({
    upload_url : "urtupload.php",
    flash_url : "swfupload/swfupload.swf",
    flash9_url : "swfupload/swfupload_fp9.swf",
        post_params: {"PHPSESSID" : "<?php echo session_id(); ?>"},
        file_size_limit : "100 MB",
        file_types : "*.zip;*.arj;*.rar;*.tar.gz;*.tgz",
        file_types_description : "All Files",
        file_upload_limit : 100,
        file_queue_limit : 1,
        file_post_name : "Filedata",
        custom_settings : {
            progressTarget : "fsUploadProgress",
            cancelButtonId : "btnCancel"
        },
        debug:false,
        // Button settings
        button_image_url: "images/ub.png",
        button_width: "61",
        button_height: "22",
        button_placeholder_id: "spanButtonPlaceHolder",
        button_text_style: ".theFont { font-size: 16; }",
        button_text_left_padding: 12,
        button_text_top_padding: 3,
        moving_average_history_size: 40,

        // The event handler functions are defined in handlers.js
        // The event handler functions are defined in handlers.js
        swfupload_preload_handler : preLoad,
        swfupload_load_failed_handler : loadFailed,
        file_queued_handler : fileQueued,
        file_queue_error_handler : fileQueueError,
        file_dialog_complete_handler : fileDialogComplete,
        upload_start_handler : uploadStart,
        upload_progress_handler : uploadProgress,
        upload_error_handler : uploadError,
        upload_success_handler : uploadSuccess,
        upload_complete_handler : uploadComplete,
        queue_complete_handler : queueComplete 
    });
```

Comment: Can you post your fileQueued and uploadError functions?

Answer (score 2):

in your method: `fileDialogComplete()`, ensure that you have the Javascript:

```
this.swfupload('startUpload');
```

This will tell your SWFU instance to start the uploads.

If you're using the example code (looks like you may be), be sure to also use/include the file 'handlers.js' (http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/simpledemo/js/handlers.js)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after making my cancel button into a .NET control.  Because .NET renamed the control, an error was being generated in fileDialogComplete and startUpload was never called.  It's in a try/catch block, so it fails silently.

Answer (score 0):

It's about the swfupload element being in a **hidden div**! As I have learned here: [swfupload sometimes stuck on "Pending..."](http://linux.goeszen.com/swfupload-stuck-on-pending.html)

Mostly it's not related to .NET or a missing startUpload() call (as the latter is a pretty standard function in any example).

Answer (score 0):

You must have some id or class missing which you are using for styling. Because i faced the same issue which got fixed when i corrected the ids and classes given for progress bar, button etc.,

Answer (score 0):

Flash Player 10: Because Flash Player 10 requires the SWFUpload swf to act is a button the movie must be visible in order for it to load. If the button_placeholder_id is set to an element that is hidden (visibility set to hidden or display set to none) SWFUpload will fail to load.